# Why am I getting IndexError while accessing a .dat file?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to access a `.dat` file. The command that I am using is `v, bv = np.loadtxt("Hyades.dat",usecols=(1,8),unpack=True,skiprows=1)`. But when I run the program I get `vals = [vals[j] for j in usecols]` and `IndexError: list index out of range`. The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v, bv = np.loadtxt("Hyades.dat",usecols=(1,8),unpack=True, skiprows=1)

plt.scatter(bv,v, marker='.',s=1.2, color='#00B2EE')
#plt.ylim(20,0)
plt.xlabel('B-V')
plt.ylabel('$M_V$')
```

Comment: Please provide the full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The error is in a different part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with loading the dat file.

You are using indices from `usecols` when indexing into `vals` (different list) which apparently is shorter so the index `j` is invalid in `vals` hence the error.

Comment: Oh okay. What can I do to fix it though?

Comment: I don't know exactly. Can you add full stack trace?